# Implement the Customized class for SOLR Spellcheker

Tags: solr, customization, solrj, spell-checking, solrcloud

We are tryin to extend the current solr.DirectSpellchecker with our own class. The reason to customize is to expand the 'maxEdits' to more than 2 characters.

Below is our implementation config (solrconfig.xml)

```
<lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">en_US</str>
    <str name="field">spellcheck_en_us</str>
    <!-- <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>-->
    <str name="classname">com.solr.spelling.CustomDirectSolrSpellChecker</str> 
    <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
    <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
    <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
    <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
    <int name="maxInspections">8</int>
    <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
    <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.0001</float>
    <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.0001</float>
    </lst>
```

we are able to create a Jar file and able to place it in one of the Lib which SOLR can read.

restarted the solr after above steps.  Didn't see any issues as the class has been accepted.

**Problem**

while calling the spellcheck query like below, we are getting NULLPOINTER error

**Query**

```
/spell?&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q=acesaries&spellcheck.dictionary=en_US&spellcheck.collate=true&wt=xml
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.getTokens(SpellCheckComponent.java:581) 
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.process(SpellCheckComponent.java:149) 
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:331) at 
org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:214) 
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2606) at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:815) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:588) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:415) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:561) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) 
t org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Unable to initiate Spellcheck Component as per the error and not sure which step we are missing here.

Our Custom changes are below

1. CustomDirectSolrSpellChecker extends org.apache.solr.spelling.DirectSolrSpellChecker
2. CustomDirectSpellChecker extends org.apache.lucene.search.spell.DirectSpellChecker
3. 1st class overriden the init method of DirectSolrSpellChecker and replaced below line

```
private DirectSpellChecker checker = new DirectSpellChecker();
```

with new line

```
private CustomDirectSpellChecker checker = new CustomDirectSpellChecker();
```

4. CustomDirectSpellChecker overriden the 'setMaxEdits' method to allow more than 2 edits.

**solr logs**

```
o.a.s.h.c.SpellCheckComponent Loading spell index for spellchecker: null
o.a.s.h.c.SpellCheckComponent Loading spell index for spellchecker: null
```

**Update(03/12/2022)**

Tried other way to Override the out of the box class rather than extending it. So I took the jar's lucene-core-8.6.3.jar, lucene-suggest-8.6.3.jar and updated the below classes with new code (only one liner change where updating maxEdits to 4 from 2)

1. DirectSpellChecker.java
2. FuzzyAutomatonBuilder.java
3. FuzzyQuery.java

After updating the existing jars and replacing them with above new class files, I got the below error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.CompiledAutomaton.<init>(CompiledAutomaton.java:154) 
at org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.CompiledAutomaton.<init>(CompiledAutomaton.java:140) 
at org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyAutomatonBuilder.buildAutomatonSet(FuzzyAutomationBuilder.java:41) 
at org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyTermsEnum$AutomatonAttributeImpl.init(FuzzyTermsEnum.java:365) 
at org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyTermsEnum.<init>(FuzzyTermsEnum.java:125) 
at org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyTermsEnum.<init>(FuzzyTermsEnum.java:92) at org.apache.lucene.search.spell.DirectSpellChecker.suggestSimilar(DirectSpellChecker.java:208) 
at org.apache.lucene.search.spell.DirectSpellChecker.suggestSimilar(DirectSpellChecker.java:179) 
at org.apache.solr.spelling.DirectSolrSpellChecker.getSuggestions(DirectSolrSpellChecker.java:197)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.process(SpellCheckComponent.java:194)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:331) 
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:214) 
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2606) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:815) at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:588) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:415) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:561) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

If i give maxEdits as 2 in the solrconfig.xml, everything working and the above error is coming when i change it to more than 2.

Can some one please help on this.

Any help on making this execute will be great help. we are using solr 8.6

Thanks In advance.

Comment: _Where_ did you change this value to allow maxEdits to be 2? That might just be a limitation of the code behind the check, so just changing the check isn't going to magically make it work.

Comment: I updated on the value on the solr config and also updated the conditions in the class files. For an instance, one of the lucene class has below condition. `public void setMaxEdits(int maxEdits) {
    if (maxEdits < 1 || maxEdits > 2)
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Invalid maxEdits"); 
    this.maxEdits = maxEdits;
  }`.  I updated such conditions to serve my purpose like max edits moved to 4 or 5.  Out of the box SOLR has this limitation and we are trying to customize that  with above mentioned ways.

Comment: Sure, but you can't just make Solr accept a larger value - the maximum number of edits are 2 in the underlying Levenshtein implementation - https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/8ac26737913d0c1555019e93bc6bf7db1ab9047e/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/LevenshteinAutomata.java#L38 You'll have to replace the actual Lucene implementation if you want to support larger edit distances (and remember that the complexity will make this a rather expensive operation)

Comment: @MatsLindh Understood. Any suggestions to achieve this(not sure how many places/classes i need to change) ? or any other way to make our spellcheck to correct more than 2 spell mistakes? Your valuable advice from your vast experience on SOLR and Lucene will help Us.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem is also a usability issue - when you allow large edit distances, you will get _many_ unrelated changes, not just those that you deem "relevant" by looking at them. "week" and "food" are four edits apart (four substitutions, but still). You might want to look at preprocessing your tokens in a different way (stemming, lemmatization, etc.), then allowing a smaller edit distance like what's already supported.